# BootRun not booting?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea

I'm getting a problem when booting `BootRun` with Gradle !!

Before, when I ran the program I could see the Spring logo and all the DB and controllers mappings, now It just keeps running without this information being displayed in the console.

I attach picture ...

Could anyone point me out what is going on here ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just click the "Toggle view" option.

In your case it's this button:

[image]

The icon may be different from one IntelliJIDEA version to another. For example in my case (IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.5 (Ultimate Edition) Build #IU-181.5281.24, built on June 12, 2018) it looks like this:

[image]